# mouse hover in not working in IE 10 with webdriver need to click on multiple submenus

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, ui-automation

need to mouse hover on menu first >menu then >submenu1 then >submenu1 then > submenu1

> > > > >
> > > >          System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","E:\workplace\AutomationTemplateWrking1\src\resource\IEDriverServer.exe");

```
     WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

 driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
 driver.get("example.com/");
 driver.findElement(By.id("user_login")).sendKeys("pmtest");
 driver.findElement(By.id("user_password")).sendKeys("@123");

 driver.findElement(By.className("login-button")).click();
 driver.manage().window().maximize();

 WebElement ele1=driver.findElement(By.id("menu"));
 WebElement ele2=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='head-fixed']/div/div/div/ul/li/ul/li/a[text()='Administration']"));
 WebElement ele3=driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[text()='Charge Codes'])[1]"));
 WebElement ele4=driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[text()='Charge Codes'])[2]"));



 Actions a1 = new Actions(driver);

 a1.moveToElement(ele1).build().perform();
 Thread.sleep(1000);
 a1.moveToElement(ele2).build().perform();
 Thread.sleep(1000);
 a1.moveToElement(ele3).build().perform();
 Thread.sleep(1000);
 ele4.click();
```

Comment: i tried  in possible ways with all capability settings and IE settings

Comment: Is the element within an iFrame?

Comment: no normal html the tests are really working gud with different browsers

Comment: Does it website work in i.e. manually?

Comment: yeah it is working properly.@marwaha

Comment: can you show the error that you get.

Comment: flikaring screen after moving to the ele2

Comment: ty @marwaha.ks@alok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution:

For me it worked with 64bit version of IEDriverServer. I added the property requireWindowFocus with "true" value: But Not able to perform on mousehovers error:stacktrace information is not available